# Use sql database with discord.js

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, discord.js

I'm creating a discord bot and I want to connect it to a SQL database to save settings, like prefixes.

I'm using the following code to connect to the database:

```js
var con = mysql.createConnection({
    host: "193.xx.xxx.xxx",
    user: "username",
    password: "password",
    database: "gu_discord"
})
```

The connection to the database is successful, but I don't know how to create default settings (eg. command prefix) for each server.

Here is my code to create the bot:

```js
const Discord = require('discord.js')
const bot = new Discord.Client()
var mysql = require('mysql')

var con = mysql.createConnection({
    host: "193.xxx.xxx.xxx",
    user: "discord",
    password: "password",
    database: "gu_discord"
})
var prefix = "!";
con.connect(function(err) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log("MySQL connected!")
});

bot.on('ready', function () {
    console.log("Bot connected!")
    bot.user.setStatus('online')
    bot.user.setActivity(prefix + "help", { type: 'LISTENING'})

    var channelid = '596622003830652938'
    var channel = bot.channels.get(channelid)
    
    console.log(bot.guilds.get('559000786655379457').id)
    
    channel.send("Connecté !")
        .then(message => console.log(`Sent message: ${message.content}`))
        .catch(console.error);
});
```

Comment: You have to also save the prefixes in the database.

Comment: I dont think one copy of bot should access multiple schemas. At best you can have multiple tables for each guilds.

Comment: @Deda Sure! but how can I get them back for each servers when I initialize bot?

Comment: You make a table `prefixes` for example, then run a querry `select * from prefixes`.

Comment: @Deda You mean a table with a key (server id) and the prefix?

Comment: @Gugu72 yeah, that is how you should do it.